# Java - creating an order link list and don't know how I got infinite recursion

Tags: java, recursion, stack-overflow

I am getting a stock overflow error when i run my code and I don't know what the problem is. Can someone help me figure this out?

Here is the method that is giving me the error. I'm pretty sure it has to do with the way I did the insert of the node recursively but I don't know what I did wrong.

The purpose of this method is to find the correct place in the link of nodes and insert the new item there. The nodes need to stay in ascending value. I hope that helps explain the purpose a little better. Thanks.

```
public class OrderedList< T extends Comparable<T> > {

    private ListNode<T> firstNode;
    private ListNode<T> lastNode;
    private String name; // the name is used in printing

    // constructor creates an empty ordered list with "ordered list" as the name
    public OrderedList() {   
        this( "ordered list" );    
    }

    // constructor creates an empty ordered list with a name
    public OrderedList( String listName ) {        
        name = listName;
        firstNode = lastNode = null;    
    }

    // insert an item into the right position of the ordered list
    public void insert( T insertItem ) {       
        if (isEmpty()) {           
            firstNode = lastNode = new ListNode<T>(insertItem);           
        }else {               
            if (insertItem.compareTo(firstNode.getData()) <= 0) {               
                firstNode = new ListNode<T>(insertItem, firstNode);               
            }else {                
                if (firstNode.equals(lastNode)) {                    
                    lastNode = new ListNode<T>(insertItem);                   
                }else {
                    T store = firstNode.getData();
                    firstNode = firstNode.getNext();                   
                    insert(insertItem);                    
                    firstNode.setNext(firstNode);
                    firstNode.setData(store);
                }
            }           
        }
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return firstNode == null;
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't given enough information to determine why it WOULDN'T continue to call `insert()` without tripping any exit conditions. i.e. what is `isEmpty()`, and what is `firstNode`.

Comment: I don't see a base case that doesn't either a) lose track of the entire list or b) make use of the first/last references effectively.  One would think that, if you had a last reference, an `insert()` would only be applied *there*...I won't downvote this question though; you should experiment and try to solve the problem, and include what you've tried to resolve the situation.

Answer (score 1):

In the last `else` block, you call `insert` again. So this is a recursive function, and recursive functions are vulnerable to stackoverflows in principle.

If you put in some println Statement, and a counter, which increments per step, you can watch what is happening.

```
else {    
            T store = firstNode.getData ();    
            firstNode = firstNode.getNext ();    
            System.out.println ("depth: " + ++depth);
            insert (insertItem);    
            --depth
            firstNode.setNext (firstNode);
            firstNode.setData (store);    
        }
```

Depth being an attribute or a static var for debugging purpose.